# iOS Rotating Phone crashes

Tags: ios, xcode

I support portrait only ATM, I get these error when rotating the device:

```
[__NSCFData setProperRotation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2dc890
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData setProperRotation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2dc890'
```

This is in iOS5.1. Initially I just left the default portrait clause in, but changed it to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) { // Or whatever orientation it will be presented in.
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I am using ARC btw.

Hoping that would help stop the crashing. My info.plist has portrait and portrait upside down.  There is nothing else I have done thats stock practice except my main view has multiple ViewControllers and its set to:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;
```

Any ideas peoples? Thanks in advance.

My project adds the main view from the appdelegate as such:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
mainViewController=[[MainViewController alloc] init];

[self.window addSubview:mainViewController.view];
```

And I have 2 ViewControllers on that mainViewController and I use a Navigation controller to push several ViewControllers as such:

```
- (void) loadActionsView {


NSArray* views = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

if ([views containsObject: actionsPanelViewController])
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:actionsPanelViewController animated:YES];
} else {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:actionsPanelViewController animated:YES];
}

[[StateModel stateModel] setCurrentScreenIndex:0];
```

}

This is the first view that is called btw.

**Update 2 with Solution/problem found:**

I was using part of SHK the SHKActivityIndicator, that had a notification that was capturing the screen rotation and its selectors where causing the issue:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:currentIndicator selector:@selector(setProperRotation) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Use CTRL+Shift+F and search for 'setProperRotation', or even just "properRotation".  Or it could be some internal NSData jankiness, NSCFData is the intermediary after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your ViewController is released and another Object receives setProperRotation message. Check if your ViewController is alive.

```
mainViewController=[[MainViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:mainViewController.view];
```

here is the problem. You adding only the view. ARC thinks that you dont need your MainViewController anymore.

- Make MainViewController as a Class variable or
- set window.rootViewController

  ```
  self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
  ```

Comment: Ok I made that change but its still crashing, not sure how to "Make MainViewController as a Class variable"?. I also think because I am adding 2 ViewControllers onto that mainViewController they are stopping the propagation of the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to that mainViewController. Thanks heaps.

Comment: i think its the same issue with actionsPanelViewController. How do you create it?

Comment: That allocated and init in MainViewController initWithNibName method. In a typical `actionsPanelViewController=[[ActivitiesPanelViewController alloc] init];` The definition is in the MainViewController header with its property set to nonatomic and retain. Could the Navigation controller be releasing it ?

Comment: try to check which controller is crashing. dont push any controller on your mainController and rotate...

Comment: That seems to be the issue, the pushing of that first controller. Its fine without pushing into the navigation controller.

Comment: check your navigationController. maybe its dead. check if you are holding a (strong) reference on it.

Comment: The navigation controller has its property definition as so : `@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;` I moved through all the VC hand made sure their property def were `strong` still crashing on rotation.

Comment: delete your app, clean, restart device, restart your mac.... create another viewController. really craze problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exception shows that you are likely over-releasing an object which is supposed to responds to `-setProperRotation`. Look for that object and try to understand where you forgot to retain it (for example, track its retains and releases with Object allocation instrument)

Comment: Updated with more details Julien.